# Make gitk with path argument show all files

Tags: git

I am running gitk with a path argument to only show commits that touch a particular file:

```
gitk -- path/to/file
```

However within these commits, in the "patch" view, gitk only shows the changes to the file(s) given on the command line.  I would instead like the patch to show all files changed in each commit, but only list commits that affect the specified file.  Is there an option to accomplish this?